# How to signal the presence of a pattern via exit code, without altering STDOUT

Tags: unix, shell, regex, grep

I need to run `cmd1`. If and only if PATTERN is missing from its STDOUT, i need to run `cmd2` too:

```
cmd1 | grep "$PATTERN"  ||  cmd2
```

But I'd like to see *all* output from cmd1, not just the lines that match PATTERN.

I know I could do something like this:

```
OUTPUT=`cmd1`
echo "$OUTPUT"
echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "$PATTERN"  ||  cmd2
```

but this would separate STDOUT from STDERR. Also I'd rather have a handy one-liner. So I am looking for an option in grep, or an alternative to grep, saying "*Don't filter, just set the exit code*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How'bout using `tee` to send the output to the tty like so:

```
cmd1 | tee /dev/tty | grep "$PATTERN"  ||  cmd2
```

Example with `PATTERN` matching `cmd1`'s output:

```
% echo "cmd1 output" | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "output" || echo "nothing matches PATTERN"
cmd1 output
```

Example with `PATTERN` not matching `cmd1`'s output:

```
% echo "cmd1 output" | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "outputttt" || echo "nothing matches PATTERN"
cmd1 output
nothing matches PATTERN
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking - tee allows a 'fork' of stdout so that it can be acted upon and also displayed unmolested.

Comment: Nicely universal, thx.